# Django REST unit test TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I'm launching the below code with the command `$ python manage.py test`, and it's returning the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

As far as I can see I'm only passing `self` to the `__init__ method`, where is this additional arg coming from?  I've checked multiple answers on here and looked at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/), but can't seem to find my error.

What is causing this?

Code:

```
import requests
import json
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import Client

class BasicFunctionality(TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        user_name = 'boris_the_blade'
        password = 'boris_the_sneaky_russian'
        self.client = Client()
        self.login_status = self.createUserAndLogin(user_name, password)

    def createUserAndLogin(self, user_name, password):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username=user_name, password=password)
        login = self.client.login(username=user_name, password=password)

        return login

    def test_login(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.login_status)
```

Full terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 56, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 603, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
File "/home/tompreston/.python_virtualenvs/lagoon-back-end-K1-2r-Ad/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 514, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.discover(start_dir=label, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 341, in discover
    tests = list(self._find_tests(start_dir, pattern))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 406, in _find_tests
    yield from self._find_tests(full_path, pattern, namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 406, in _find_tests
    yield from self._find_tests(full_path, pattern, namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 398, in _find_tests
    full_path, pattern, namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 452, in _find_test_path
    return self.loadTestsFromModule(module, pattern=pattern), False
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 123, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 92, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.addTests(tests)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/suite.py", line 57, in addTests
    for test in tests:
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't override the `__init__` method of `TestCase` to set up test data in the database. Use [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) instead.

```
def setUp(self):
    user_name = 'boris_the_blade'
    password = 'boris_the_sneaky_russian'
    self.client = Client()  # Django's TestCase already sets self.client so this line isn't required
    self.login_status = self.createUserAndLogin(user_name, password)
```

Comment: B-e-a-utiful!  Thanks